# Однородные определения в конце предложения. Запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, однородные-члены, определения

*Странно было видеть, как то там, то тут в грязи лежали тела итарков, жалкие, поникшие, ничем не отличимые от тел их соплеменников.*
Уместнее ли будет вместо запятой поставить тире после "тела итарков"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в конце предложения следует ряд однородных определений, то ставится тире. Пример есть в [этой главе (пункт 1)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108):

> Меня всегда интересовал этот дом в старинном переулке — мрачно-таинственный, благородный всем своим видом, ни на один другой не похожий

[Вот еще пример из Розенталя (пункт 2, конец примечаний)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119):

> Рядом с этими домами высятся другие здания — жилые, административные, торговые.

Где-то еще в справочнике было такое предложение с тире, но я не помню где.

Comment: "...может отделяться не запятой,  а тире" ≠ "...ставится тире".

Answer (score 2):

> Определения, стоящие в конце предложения, как нераспространенные, так и с зависимыми словами, **могут** отделяться знаком тире. Такие определения имеют пояснительно-уточняющее значение: *От результатов этой борьбы зависит, в конечном счете, человеческое счастье — **настоящее и будущее*** (Аст.)...

Так что постановка тире вполне уместна, даже предпочтительна.
Тем временем в столовую явились вчерашние новоиспеченные **― помятые, вялые и, видимо, страдающие**. [В. С. Трубецкой. Записки кирасира (1936-1937)]

А вот употребление в этом предложении причастия *поникшие* мне кажется некорректным (я бы использовала другое определение).
[тело](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE)
4. Останки умершего человека; мёртвый человек, труп. *Прощание с телом. Везти тело на отпевание. Кремировать тело. Предать тело земле* (похоронить). / О людях, лежащих неподвижно. *Сонные, распростёртые на полу тела.*
[поникнуть](https://all_words.academic.ru/68641/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C) (2)
а) Утратить бодрость духа, впасть в подавленное настроение.
б) отт. Склонить, нагнуть (*голову*).

*Странно было видеть, как то там, то тут в грязи лежали тела итарков — жалкие, растерзанные, ничем не отличимые от тел их соплеменников.*

[Знаки препинания при обособленных согласованных определениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118)